# Jquery Ajax beforeSend and success,error & complete

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, recursion

I have a problem with multiple ajax functions where the `beforeSend` of the *second* ajax post is executed before the `complete` function of the *first* ajax.

The loading class I am adding to the placeholder before sending is working for the first ajax call. However soon after the first ajax request completes the class is removed and never appends again on the second and further calls (remember recursive calls).

While debugging it shows that the `beforeSend` function of the second ajax call is called first and the `complete` function of the first ajax call is called later. Which is obvious, because the return data inserted in the page from the first ajax call starts the second call.

In short it's mixed up. Is there any way this can be sorted out?

The function code is as follows

```
function AjaxSendForm(url, placeholder, form, append) {
var data = $(form).serialize();
append = (append === undefined ? false : true); // whatever, it will evaluate to true or false only
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: url,
    data: data,
    beforeSend: function() {
        // setting a timeout
        $(placeholder).addClass('loading');
    },
    success: function(data) {
        if (append) {
            $(placeholder).append(data);
        } else {
            $(placeholder).html(data);
        }
    },
    error: function(xhr) { // if error occured
        alert("Error occured.please try again");
        $(placeholder).append(xhr.statusText + xhr.responseText);
        $(placeholder).removeClass('loading');
    },
    complete: function() {
        $(placeholder).removeClass('loading');
    },
    dataType: 'html'
});
}
```

And the data contains the following snippet of javascript/jquery which checks and starts another ajax request.

```
<script type="text/javascript">//<!--
 $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#restart').val(-1)
    $('#ajaxSubmit').click();
});
//--></script>
```

Answer (score 102):

Maybe you can try the following :

```
var i = 0;
function AjaxSendForm(url, placeholder, form, append) {
var data = $(form).serialize();
append = (append === undefined ? false : true); // whatever, it will evaluate to true or false only
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: url,
    data: data,
    beforeSend: function() {
        // setting a timeout
        $(placeholder).addClass('loading');
        i++;
    },
    success: function(data) {
        if (append) {
            $(placeholder).append(data);
        } else {
            $(placeholder).html(data);
        }
    },
    error: function(xhr) { // if error occured
        alert("Error occured.please try again");
        $(placeholder).append(xhr.statusText + xhr.responseText);
        $(placeholder).removeClass('loading');
    },
    complete: function() {
        i--;
        if (i <= 0) {
            $(placeholder).removeClass('loading');
        }
    },
    dataType: 'html'
});
}
```

This way, if the `beforeSend` statement is called before the `complete` statement `i` will be greater than 0 so it will not remove the class. Then only the last call will be able to remove it.

I cannot test it, let me know if it works or not.

Comment: I tried your solution and it gave me surprising results. First of all I used the var requestNumber = 0 and ++ it in beforeSend and checked it in complete/always. It shows the requestNumber == 2 and -- results in 1 which returns false in the check and loading class isn't removed. However it is never removed because I don't know why, it is generating one additional request for the whole sequence. Now the culprit is found, I think it's easy to resolve or post a bug request.

Comment: If the function fails, then it goes to error as well as complete. What if I only want it at complete, can I `return 1` at the end of complete so it doesn't go to error?

Answer (score 11):

It's actually much easier with [jQuery's promise API](http://api.jquery.com/promise/):

```
$.ajax(
            type: "GET",
            url: requestURL,
        ).then((success) =>
            console.dir(success)
        ).failure((failureResponse) =>
            console.dir(failureResponse)
        )
```

Alternatively, you can pass in of `bind` functions to each result callback; the order of parameters is: `(success, failure)`.  So long as you specify a function with at least 1 parameter, you get access to the response.  So, for example, if you wanted to check the response text, you could simply do:

```
$.ajax(
            type: "GET",
            url: @get("url") + "logout",
            beforeSend: (xhr) -> xhr.setRequestHeader("token", currentToken)
        ).failure((response) -> console.log "Request was unauthorized" if response.status is 401
```

Comment: Thanks for the update, I updated my code and replaced success, error and complete callback functions with the newly defined, promised functions fail, done and always. However they did not resolves the problem because the problem was something different as I applied the solution provided by @Nathan P