# CSS animation high CPU usage

Tags: css, css-animations

I am working on a loading component and using this codepen as a reference

Check out here --> [Code](https://codepen.io/ryanaltvater/pen/QEbpLZ)

The CPU usage hikes up as soon as I test this out. I tried to add these, as suggested on other posts but the animation stops,

```
transform: translateZ(0) or will-change: transform
```

Any suggestions

Comment: Did you add the `will-change` to the correct element?
Also, have you tried adding `opacity` to the `will-change`? You can do `will-change: transform, opacity;`. Mostly because of the gradient and the element being rotated. Not sure if this will make a difference though.

Comment: it didn't help.

Comment: This is one of those tricky ones. Sorry, don't have other ideas :\

Answer (score 0):

You can use .gif image file instead of creating new one like you are trying.

I don't know where you gonna use that feature.

But Ajax has an attribute called 'beforeSend'.

ref: [Jquery Ajax beforeSend and success,error & complete](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21648356/jquery-ajax-beforesend-and-success-error-complete)

And also, if you want to implement it while a page is being loading. Then, you can implement it like below.

ref: [Can I run javascript before the whole page is loaded?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2920129/can-i-run-javascript-before-the-whole-page-is-loaded)

I hope this is helpful.