# Displaying a loading.gif at the beginning of a jquery script and displaying him off when the script ends

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation, sequence

I am using a jQuery script to load data from database on a select change of an HTML form.

My intention is, to start a loading animation when the select has changed and the data is loading from database, at least the loading animation disappears.

```
<div id="spinner" style="display:none">
   <img class="loading" src="img/Fidget-spinner.gif" alt="loading">
</div>
```

```
function onSelectChange(){
    $("#spinner").removeAttr("style");
    
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "loadpreise.php?artikelnummer="+artikelnummer+"&veredelung="+veredelung+"&menge="+menge,
        data: "data",
        success: function(data){
        $('#ziel').empty();
        $('#ziel').html(data);
        }
    });

    $("#spinner").attr("style", "display:none")
}
```

- A) At first i remove the Style Element for the ID Spinner to make it appear.
- B) Then the data is loading and giving result
- C) At least i add the display:none to the ID spinner.

My Problem:
Everything works fine, but not in the way i want. ;- )
I added in my `loadpreise.php` a pause of 3 seconds, but the sequence of executions the different part are:

- A) Remove Style
- C) Add Style
- B) Data is Loading an giving result

Do you have any idea to come to the right sequence in execution? I thought the individual parts of the JavaScript script would be executed one after the other.

Thank you very much.

Comment: Data loading is asynchronous. This part finishes last. Try putting `$("#spinner").attr("style", "display:none")` into the `success:` function. 

Comment: `beforeSend` could do what you want. Read more about it in [the official documentation](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/). If you need a specific example, please see [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21648616/6133426).